# ( Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ) - What to do?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

On the page there is this script:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=<?=$appID?>&client_secret=<?=$sequreKey?>&code=<?=$code?>&redirect_uri=<?=$redirect?>",
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        window.location.href = "/index.php?json="+data;
    }
});
</script>
```

After running it I get an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

And it is on the page (https://oauth.vk.com/access_tok...):

```
{"access_token":"3de258836055120725cef2dec546187f8f5eed0716200ec5cb09f6466a61b1968752e1a36f16ded46e3a2","expires_in":86399,"user_id":167014478}
```

How to run it?:

```
window.location.href = "/index.php?json="+data;
```

Comment: Please replace the PHP code with its result, i.e. with the code that the browser gets. I guess the solution is in there, because the rest of the code seems to be just fine

Comment: Every time codes are different so do not get it done

Comment: I'm pretty sure redirect_uri should be static...if vk oauth works like facebook's it's set in the application's configurations.

Comment: http://pwos.udevteam.com/worm/worm.php - see the console(it's redirect uri)

Comment: I've been redirected to vk login page. Can you just paste the snippet with php variable echoed and not the php source code?

Comment: Like this? - https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=4395864&client_secret=Pq041Lnrdy05kaaUEih3&code=<?=$code?>&redirect_uri=pwos.udevteam.com/worm/worm.php

Comment: Nope. Visit the page where you have the snippet you pasted. Inspect the source in the browser, and paste here the code from the browser.

Comment: {"access_token":"1b4cb3dde00a95f49cf8328947d590183be78707e337ef779fc0b329355f80d44069673290157749ead65","expires_in":86399,"user_id":167014478}

Comment: You try to use JSONP, but the API returns plain JSON. Does it support JSONP at all?

Comment: But I want to get content of page on other domen...

Comment: You are appending the result of the ajax call to the query string of the redirect...I can't figure out what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short explanation of the differences between JSON and JSONP

JSON is a string format representing an object literal in Javascript notation.

Example:

```
'{"number":36, "sqrt": 6}'
```

JSONP is a string format representing a Javascript method call ideally containing JSON as a parameter to this method call

Example:

```
mycallback('{"number":36, "sqrt": 6}');
```

If a service provides JSON responses it does not automatically provide JSONP responses. The server script must be explicitly configured to do so. You cannot assume that your server script provides you with JSONP functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that url is a valid string? Maybe you are echoing a variable (most likely $redirect), which contains double quotes, so it breaks javascript syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so only on server - side:
[VK developer answer](https://vk.com/topic-1_24428376?post=79396).
If you want to do authorization in JavaScript you should use another way:
[VK dev intro](https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile).

There is another value for param response_type:

```
...response_type=token...
```